# Sequelize BelongsToMany: custom column in WHERE clause

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have this 3 models:

```
var User = sequelize.define('users', {
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        field: 'name' 
    }
});

var Book = sequelize.define('books', {
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        field: 'name' 
    }
});

var UserBook = sequelize.define('userbook', {
    validated: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'validated',
        defaultValue: 0
    }
});

Book.belongsToMany(User, {through: UserBook, foreignKey: 'bookId'});
User.belongsToMany(Book, {through: UserBook, foreignKey: 'userId'});
```

Now I want to get books for a user where validated=1

I have tried this:

```
User.findOne({
    where: { id: req.session.user.id }
})
.then(function(user){
    user.getBooks({
        through: { validated: 1 }
    })
    .then(function(books){
        return res.json({success: true, books: books});
    })
});
```

But it returns all books without checking for validated=1

How to get all books with validated=1 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've you tried this :

```
User.findOne({
  where: { id: req.session.user.id }
})
  .then(function (user) {
    user.getBooks({
      where: { validated: 1 }
    })
      .then(function (books) {
        return res.json({ success: true, books: books });
      })
  });
```

?

Edit (it works):

```
User.findById(req.session.user.id, {
  include: [
    {
      model: Book,
      through: {
        where: { validated: 1 }
      }
    }
  ]
}).then((user) => {
  console.log(user);
})
```

Comment: Yes but it throws this error: `ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'books.validated' in where clause`

Comment: What's the result of this :User.findById(req.session.user.id, {
  include: [
    {
      model: Book,
      through: {
        where: { validated: 1 }
      }
    }
  ]
}).then((user) => {
  console.log(user);
})